# What does a spirit primary type advantage do?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

When introduced to spirits, the game shows the chart below and explains a rock, paper, scissors relationship between non-neutral primary spirit types.

[image: Primary Type Advantage Chart]

Clearly if I'm challenging a Shield spirit, I should use a Grab spirit, or at least avoid using an Attack spirit, but why?

For example, if I'm challenging a lvl 10k Shield spirit and I've got both a lvl 10k Shield spirit and a lvl 8k Grab spirit, which one is the better choice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After running a few tests, it looks like having a type advantage increases damage by roughly **30%**, which having a type disadvantage decreases damage dealt by about **15%**.

---

To test this I took 3 spirits with equal attack values and made teams out of them:

- **Kammy Koopa**, Atk 500, Attack Type
- **Porygon**, Atk 500, Shield Type
- **Staryu**, Atk 500, Grab Type

The Porygon also has 500 Def and will be used as the target for these tests, hoping that having Atk and Def even out helps us focus on just the type advantage results.

[image: Type Advantage Lab Rats]

Then I went into training mode and tested by using fully charged side smash attacks with Marth.

When testing with the same times (Shield vs Shield), I dealt **20.1%** damage

[image: Porygon Attack Case]

When testing with a type advantage (Grab vs Shield), I dealt **26.2%** damage

[image: How does a Staryu even grab?]

When testing with a type disadvantage (Attack vs Shield), I dealt **17.1%** damage

[image: Kammy Koopa attacks with a Type Disadvantage]

---

If you divide the standard results with the advantage results (26.2/20.1) you get 1.303. So a type advantage grants roughly **30%** extra damage output.

Dividing these standard results with the disadvantage results (17.1/20.1) you get 0.850. A type disadvantage thus reduces damage output by roughly **15%**.

---

For a second test, I repeated the general steps from above but this time with Atk and Def values around 1000 to see if the results remain consistent.

Here I chose **Urbosa** (Attack, 1011 Atk), **Blooper** (Shield, 1003 Atk), **Solidus Snake** (Grab, 994 Atk), and **Houndoom** (Attack, 997 Def).

(*The Atk values aren't exact with this test, but a quick test with two spirits with a 16 point difference in Atk values dealt the same damage in this test, so I'm assuming here that the differences are minor enough to not largely effect the results.*)

[image: Stats from second batch of testers]

After repeating the test, I got:

- No Advantage: **19.1%**
- Advantage: **24.8%**
- Disadvantage: **16.2%**

The previous calculation here yields 1.298 (vs the previous 1.303) and 0.848 (vs the previous 0.850).

---

To be extra thorough, I tried this test one last time but with the 1000 Atk spirits vs the 500 Def Porygon spirit.

- No Advantage: **23.5%**
- Advantage: **30.5%**
- Disadvantage: **19.9%**

This gives 1.297 and 0.846, which stays in line with the original 30% and 15% estimates.

Comment: Note that "Power" is the sum of Offensive and Defensive power. Since Dark Matter has the greater Offensive power, it explains why he deals more damage to James than James does, despite having type disadvantage.

Comment: Something else that may be affecting these test results, according to one of the wiki's for the game: "Equipping a fighter with a Primary Spirit from the same series as the fighter gives a 10% bonus to the spirit's stats". Dark Matter is from the Kirby series, which means he's giving an attack and defense buff to the Kirby's in the first and last test if this is true.

Comment: Great points, both of you. I'd really love to see some more testing done on this, so I made it a community wiki. Please add any data that you can

Comment: Side note, @Nolonar, how did you upload screenshots to imgur? Did you still have to go through twitter?

Comment: @CornSmith. I went through Twitter (I have a private Twitter account, which I only use for Switch screenshots). I could also remove my SD card, but that's not really worth it, in my opinion.

Comment: Still trying to figure this out, but I got 3 spirits of the 3 main types with exactly 500 attack each, and a shield spirit with 500 defense. Testing with Marth's smash attack and no same series bonus (or any other bonuses), I got 20.1% with no advantage, 26.2% with advantage, and 17.1% with disadvantage. I want to now get the same setup with higher stats to test again, since Attack and Defense stats don't perfectly cancel each other out (same test with Marth but with exactly 4426 attack vs 4426 defense gave 16.5%).

Comment: Same test from above comment with attack and defense stats at ~1000. No advantage: 19.1%, Advantage: 24.8%, Disadvantage: 16.2%. Seems like advantage lets you deal an extra ~30% while disadvantage makes you deal 15% less damage? I'll update the answer if a bit more testing shows this is consistent.

Comment: @Question-Marks Please do update the answer! You've got some great test results here with very useful data

Comment: @QuestionMarks Awesome edit! This wiki is looking great! I love seeing videogame science being done